# Logstash 7.2 file input plugin network path wildcard didn’t produce any out on Windows x64

Tags: ruby, windows-server-2016

I have a remote file storage with thousands having 10mb average size text files. I'm using this code:

```
input {
file {
path => "//foldername/**/*.dat"
start_position => "beginning"
}
}
output {
file {
path => "C:/foo/foo.txt"
}
}
```

Logstash was started successfully and repeats flush cycle. Java is starting load network on Logstash startup. But Logstash doesn't open output file to write incoming data for more than 5 hours. When I'm using in path

> //foldername/name1/name2/*/*.dat

it works and with

> //foldername/*/*/*/*.dat

it doesn't. I have three level depth with random folders names name1, name2 and name3 that I can't predict. Over the internet manuals this paths are correct in the ruby glob meaning. --debug run didn't represent bugs.

What's the problem? Is there any workaround?